# What is the most safe and correct way to paint on a TFrame surface?

Tags: delphi, frame, delphi-xe, paint

I have a frame in my project (`TFrame`'s descendant) and want to paint something on it.

As I could see from forums, the common way to do that is to override `PaintWindow` method.

I tried this on a clean project:

```
type
  TMyFrame = class(TFrame)
  private
    FCanvas: TCanvas;
  protected
    procedure PaintWindow(DC: HDC); override;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy(); override;
  end;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

constructor TMyFrame.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  FCanvas := TCanvas.Create();
end;

destructor TMyFrame.Destroy();
begin
  FCanvas.Free();
  inherited;
end;

procedure TMyFrame.PaintWindow(DC: HDC);
begin
  inherited;
  FCanvas.Handle := DC;
  FCanvas.Pen.Width := 3;
  FCanvas.Pen.Color := clRed;
  FCanvas.MoveTo(0, 0);
  FCanvas.LineTo(ClientWidth, ClientHeight);
  FCanvas.Pen.Color := clGreen;
  FCanvas.MoveTo(ClientWidth, 0);
  FCanvas.LineTo(0, ClientHeight);
end;
```

However, after putting my frame on a main form, **the debugger was never entering this method, until I enabled `DoubleBuffered` in frame's properties**. Any value of `ParentBackground` did not affect the result.

Overriding `WM_PAINT` handler solves problem too:

```
type
  TMyFrame = class(TFrame)
  protected
    procedure WMPaint(var Message: TWMPaint); message WM_PAINT;
  ...

procedure TMyFrame.WMPaint(var Message: TWMPaint);
begin
  inherited;
  FCanvas.Handle := GetDC(Handle);
  FCanvas.Pen.Width := 3;
  FCanvas.Pen.Color := clRed;
  FCanvas.MoveTo(0, 0);
  FCanvas.LineTo(ClientWidth, ClientHeight);
  FCanvas.Pen.Color := clGreen;
  FCanvas.MoveTo(ClientWidth, 0);
  FCanvas.LineTo(0, ClientHeight);
  ReleaseDC(Handle, FCanvas.Handle);
end;
```

this code draws the crossing lines always, no matter which values were assigned to `DoubleBuffered` or `ParentBackground`.

But when I tried to use `BeginPaint` / `EndPaint` instead of `GetDC` / `ReleaseDC`, the problem returned:

```
procedure TMyFrame.WMPaint(var Message: TWMPaint);
var
  PS: PAINTSTRUCT;
begin
  inherited;
  FCanvas.Handle := BeginPaint(Handle, PS);
  FCanvas.Pen.Width := 3;
  FCanvas.Pen.Color := clRed;
  FCanvas.MoveTo(0, 0);
  FCanvas.LineTo(ClientWidth, ClientHeight);
  FCanvas.Pen.Color := clGreen;
  FCanvas.MoveTo(ClientWidth, 0);
  FCanvas.LineTo(0, ClientHeight);
  EndPaint(Handle, PS);
end;
```

FCanvas.Handle is non-zero, but the result is a blank frame. In this case setting `DoubleBuffered` or `ParentBackground` not changing anything.

Maybe I'm calling them wrong?

Now I use `WM_PAINT` handler with `GetDC` / `ReleaseDC`, because I don't want to enable `DoubleBuffered` on this frame. Also I'm afraid other programmers will accidentally disable `DoubleBuffered` after putting my frame into their projects and will have the same headache as I have.

But maybe there are more safe and correct ways to paint on frame's surface?

Comment: Is the issue related to the fact that frames have the `csParentBackground` control style? Which means that they don't do any painting at all. Not my specialist subject though.

Comment: Unable to reproduce. Could you provide more specifics on the issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can duplicate your issue if I don't place any control on the test frame (this is also probably the reason why none of us could duplicate your issue - f.i. throw a control to make visually sure the frame is on the form).

The reason `PaintHandler` is not called when there are no controls on it, and the reason when it is called when `DoubleBuffered` is set although there are no controls on it, is simply how `WM_PAINT` message handler of `TWinControl` is designed:

```
procedure TWinControl.WMPaint(var Message: TWMPaint);
var
  ..
begin
  if not FDoubleBuffered or (Message.DC <> 0) then
  begin
    if not (csCustomPaint in ControlState) and (ControlCount = 0) then
      inherited
    else
      PaintHandler(Message);
  end
  else
  begin
    ..
```

As you can see, when `DoubleBuffered` is not set and when there are no controls, `PaintHandler` is not called (after all there's nothing to paint: we are not custom drawing (no csCustomPaint flag) and also there are no controls to show). When `DoubleBuffered` is set, a different code path is followed which calls `WMPrintClient`, which in turn calls `PaintHandler`.

If you're gonna end up using the frame without any controls on it (though unlikely), the fix is evident (also sensible when you know it) from the code piece above: include `csCustomPaint` in `ControlState`:

```
type
  TMyFrame = class(TFrame)
    ..
  protected
    procedure WMPaint(var Message: TWMPaint); message WM_PAINT;
  ..

procedure TMyFrame.WMPaint(var Message: TWMPaint);
begin
  ControlState := ControlState + [csCustomPaint];
  inherited;
  ControlState := ControlState - [csCustomPaint];
end;
```

then the inherited `WM_PAINT` handler will call `PaintHandler`.

---

As for why painting using `BeginPaint`/`EndPaint` in the `WM_PAINT` message handler does not seem to work, the reason is that the `inherited` call preceding your painting code validates the update region. Check your `rcPaint` member of your `PAINTSTRUCT` after you call `BeginPaint`, you'll find it to be (0, 0, 0, 0).

Since there's no invalidated region left then, the OS just disregards following drawing calls. You can verify this by invalidating the client rectangle of the frame before drawing on the canvas:

```
procedure TMyFrame.WMPaint(var Message: TWMPaint);
var
  PS: PAINTSTRUCT;
begin
  inherited;
  InvalidateRect(Handle, nil, False);      // <- here
  FCanvas.Handle := BeginPaint(Handle, PS);
  FCanvas.Pen.Width := 3;
  FCanvas.Pen.Color := clRed;
  FCanvas.MoveTo(0, 0);
  FCanvas.LineTo(ClientWidth, ClientHeight);
  FCanvas.Pen.Color := clGreen;
  FCanvas.MoveTo(ClientWidth, 0);
  FCanvas.LineTo(0, ClientHeight);
  EndPaint(Handle, PS);
end;
```

and now you'll see your drawing will take effect. Of course you may choose to not to call `inherited` instead, or invalidate only the portion you'll draw onto.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like its only called when its in the designer

```
procedure TCustomFrame.PaintWindow(DC: HDC);
begin
   // Paint a grid if designing a frame that paints its own background
   if (csDesigning in ComponentState) and (Parent is TForm) then
   with TForm(Parent) do
      if (Designer <> nil) and (Designer.GetRoot = Self) and
         (not StyleServices.Enabled or not Self.ParentBackground) then
          Designer.PaintGrid
   end;
```

The only way to do some special paint is to add the WM_PAINT to your frame:

```
TFrame3 = class(TFrame)
protected
  procedure WMPaint(var Message: TWMPaint); message WM_PAINT;
end;
```

Comment: The fact that the implementation of `TCustomFrame.PaintWindow` only does work when designing, in no way implies that the function is not called. It would be more usual to override the `Paint` method in any case, rather than intercepting `WM_PAINT`.

Comment: When I use WM_PAINT handler, the Message.DC is always 0;

Comment: @DavidHeffernan It's impossible to override `Paint` method, because it's not in the base class.

Comment: But I speak incorrectly here. `TFrame` does not support the `Paint` method.

Comment: ok, I just have to use `GetDC` / `ReleaseDC`, because the  Message.DC is always 0.

Comment: No, Andrew, `GetDC` is *not* the function to call. Use `BeginPaint`.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan What's wrong with an answer? It works on WM_PAINT

Comment: @RobKennedy I just checked the `BeginPaint`/`EndPaint` on frame handle - the HDC returned is non-zero, but nothing painted in the end. Maybe there must be some special invalidation?

Comment: Maybe. Ask a new question with the details of what you're seeking and what you've tried. What we're discussing here in the comments of an incorrect answer have nothing to do with the main question here. (This answer is incorrect because it gives no explanation of why `PaintWindow` wouldn't be called when you run in the debugger. It also contains an incorrect analysis of the quoted code. It might have helped you get toward the solution to your *real* problem, but it doesn't answer the *question you asked*.)

Comment: @RobKennedy Now I understand, thanks. I'll edit the question little later.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan and Rob Kennedy, I edited the question, need your review.